# How to kill the Session of User when he LoggedOut in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, logout

I have a asp.net web application login page which has buil-in Authentication of asp.net and login.aspx page created by Login control of asp.net. Now i have a problem in logout.

When user pressed "Logout" the link is redirected to "Login.aspx" page. But, when the user press "Back" button from the browser the user "Login"to the page to the application which i want to avoid and it must ask to enter Login Credentials.

Help Appreciated..!
Thanks in Advace..!

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
   protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();

        Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply..! but, this but does not work...When he press the "Back" button of Browser again he logged in to the web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MasterPage` then in the **Code Behind** of your MasterPage, you can do this

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Expires = -1500;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

Also do not forget to clear the Session while Logging off.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Session.RemoveAll();
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 

FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```